# How to filter tab delimited text file that selects lines that start with certain string and convert to a CSV

Tags: python

I have a text file that is tab delimited and I want to only select lines that start with a certain string. Then I want to take those lines and convert it to a CSV file. I was able to do this, but in the excel csv, each line from the text file is split into 3 cells in a row in the csv and within each cell, there are still tabs. Also, it skips every other row.

I tried replacing tabs with commas, but it didn't work.

```py
#parse APT.txt for airport data
import pandas as pd
import csv
import itertools

airport_data = source

APT_lines = []

for line in open(airport_data):
    if line.startswith('APT'):
        APT_lines.append(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(APT_lines)
df.to_csv('apt.csv', header=False, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
```

Comment: Have you tried df = pd.read_csv(filename) and maybe playing with the delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

The csv module in python handles tab-delimited files as well as comma-separated values.  I think you want to do something like this:

```
import csv
with open(input_file,newline='') as csvfile, open(output_file, 'w+', newline='') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimited=',',quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) != 0 and row[0].startswith('APT'):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

(I haven't tested this code and you might find typos in it; but the CSV module is a pleasure to work with.  I recommend reading the file directly as CSV, and then using the CSV module with the desired settings to write it back out.)